# First time using arrays, getting an error that 'x was not declared in this scope' however I did declare it?

Tags: c++, arrays

My compiler keeps saying that 'small' and 'x' were not declared in this scope, how do I fix my array so that they are accurately displayed? overall the code is supposed to find the smallest positive nonzero value stored in the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int findthesmall( int small[x], int y) 
{
  for(int i=0; i< y; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< y; j++){
      int temp = small[i];
      if( small[i] > small[j] )
      small[i] = small[j];
      small[j] = temp;
    }
  }
  return small[0];

}

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: use pointer or reference, like `const int* small`

Comment: I had already seen variable-length arrays, but not variable-length arrays in arguments (where is `x` defined, anyways?)

Comment: You don't need temp unless you enter the if statement so I would move it inside the if statement, to limit the scope.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need:

```
int findthesmall( int* small, int y) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int findthesmall( int small[], int y) {
   for(int i=0; i< y; i++){
      for(int j=0; j< y; j++){
         int temp = small[i];

         if( small[i] > small[j] )
            small[i] = small[j];
         small[j] = temp;
      }
   }
   return small[0];

}

int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: size of the array is not specified. could lead to issues

Comment: @KarthikT I believe it's passed as `y`.

Comment: @JanDvorak ah apologies, i assumed OP was passing it as `x`

Answer (score 1):

```
int small[x]
```

This is illegal for 2 reasons.

- Like your compiler says, X is undefined
- Size of the array cannot be set to the value of a non compile time constant.

To fix this you can do what @ajon suggested( pass array as pointer + length), it is historically the way to pass arrays.

There are other better ways in C++ though.

- You can consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Both of them can be passed as you would any other variable, know their own size, and can be accessed like a normal array
- Or you could use `template` code to capture the size of the array automatically.

  `template<int  len>`
  `int findthesmall(int (&small)[len]){`

The 2nd option maybe a little convoluted and more complex than other options, especially now that you  have got your answer, I'm just including it here for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other answers, there is also a bug in the logic. If your function is just to find the smallest element as function name indicated, one for loop should be enough. 
Sample code presented below:

```
int findthesmall( int small[], int y) 
{
  int temp = small[0];
  for(int i=1; i< y; i++)
  {
  if( temp > small[i] )
      temp = small[i];
  }
  return temp; 
}
```

Or you could use std::min_element algorithm as well

```
std::cout << *std::min_element(small, small+y) << std::endl;
```

Comment: are you referring to the missing curly braces?